# LMDE 1 Stuck on Terminal after Login

Tags: terminal, login, mate-desktop, lmde

Currently running LMDE 1 with Mate for 6 months now and still acquainting myself with it. I had installed VirtualBox but after restart and successful log in I am stuck on Terminal. I have updated and believed I had uninstalled VirtualBox but to no avail.  I need to keep my internet history intact and so avoiding full reinstall if it overwrites that.  Recovery Partition also does the same and boots to terminal. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

SOLVED: After much searching around i went ahead and followed the commands here, installing Gnome in place which seems to work fine. 
http://ralph.soika.com/debian-gdm3-gnome-broken-dist-upgrade/

Comment: what do you mean by "boots to terminal" is it booting to a terminal login screen and you would like it to be graphical? is it freezing while loading?

Comment: It was supposed to be booting to Mate GUI Desktop. There was no freezing.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you may be able to advance beyond where you are by logging in and then as root type: `init 5` or `startx`

if the `init 5` worked, you can edit `/etc/inittab` and change

```
# The default runlevel.
id:3:initdefault:
```

to

```
# The default runlevel.
id:5:initdefault:
```

Comment: As root `init 5` did nothing, no output at all. The same for `Startx`. I went and installed Gnome over the top, it seemed to work.